# Workflow to model part of Bus

Tags: modeling

[image]how can i part this model especially that with red line. I am new in Blender and i need spme Tips and Workflow. Thanks alot. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposition for your topology (a bit different version and more detailed):

[image]

Comment: very nice how did you make it. can you please write  steps

Comment: ok I'll try to do it   ;)

Comment: i edit my question. How can i make it  more circle as red line and how to make this thing with arrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks very much that is very helpful